# adding values to an array using counter

Tags: java, arrays

I've been learning java for the last 1.5 month. Now the instructor has asked us to create a program that take the name and phone number (but in a method) from the user until the user enters "E". The program should then print all the information stored in the all the arrays.

The program has a main menu and the user will enter "1" to create an account (name and phone number) and then the main menu appears again and the user create another account and so on and so forth... until he chooses another option from the menu or enter "E" to exist and print the summary for all the accounts.

My problem is that I tried to create a counter as a references to each account spot in the arrays(index in array); so after each time the user enters a name and a number the counter add 1 and the arrays index add 1 and moves to the next spot… but that didn't work.

I didn't complete the code, stopped at choice 1 to test the create account method

```
    public static void addDonor(String[] a1, String[] a2, char[] a3, int[] a4, int [] a5){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("  Enter the name (first and last):" + " ");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("  Enter Mobile No.:" + " ");
    String phone = input.next();

    if (phone.length() < 10 && phone.startsWith("0") == false){
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Wrong Mobile NO... try again!");
            System.out.print("  Enter Mobile No.:" + " ");
            phone = input.next();
            if (phone.length() > 10 || phone.startsWith("0") == true)
                break;
        }
    }

    System.out.print("  Enter Blood Group Type (A, B or O):" + " ");
    char blood =  input.next().charAt(0);

        while (blood != 'a' || blood != 'b' || blood != 'c'){
            System.out.println("Wrong Blood Group Type... try again!");
            System.out.println("    Enter Blood Group Type (A, B or O):" + " ");
            blood =  input.next().charAt(0);
            if (blood == 'A' || blood == 'B' || blood == 'O')
                break;    
        }
        int counter = 0;
        a1[counter] = name;
        a2[counter] = phone;
        a3[counter] = blood;
        a4[counter] = 1;
        a5[counter] = 1;
        counter++;

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] Name = new String[20];
        String[] Mobile = new String[20];
        char[] Blood_Gp = new char[20];
        int[] Count_o_Donation = new int[20];
        int[] Blood_Stock = new int[20];



        while (true){
            displayMainMenu();
        readAndVerify();
        String choice = readAndVerify();

            switch (choice){
                case "1":
                    addDonor(Name, Mobile, Blood_Gp, Count_o_Donation, Blood_Stock);
                    break;
            }
           if (choice.equals("e")) 
               break;
        }


        System.out.println(Name[0]);
        System.out.println(Name[1]);



}
```

Comment: the choice.equals("e") can be moved inside the switch. you can add a label to the while(true) to break from the while inside the switch. (google java label break example)

Comment: Simplify your life, use List, not Arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is thar you are creating the variable index inside the addDonor method. So everytime the method is invoked a new variable with value 0 is going to be created, that's why it's not moving. You should create the varible outside the method and pass it as parameter.

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] Name = new String[20];
    String[] Mobile = new String[20];
    char[] Blood_Gp = new char[20];
    int[] Count_o_Donation = new int[20];
    int[] Blood_Stock = new int[20];
    int index = 0;

    while (true){
        displayMainMenu();
    readAndVerify();
    String choice = readAndVerify();

        switch (choice){
            case "1":
                addDonor(Name, Mobile, Blood_Gp, Count_o_Donation, Blood_Stock, index);
                index++
                break;
        }
       if (choice.equals("e")) 
           break;
    }


    System.out.println(Name[0]);
    System.out.println(Name[1]);

}

   public static void addDonor(String[] a1, String[] a2, char[] a3, int[] a4, int [] a5), int index{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("  Enter the name (first and last):" + " ");
String name = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("  Enter Mobile No.:" + " ");
String phone = input.next();

if (phone.length() < 10 && phone.startsWith("0") == false){
    while (true){
        System.out.println("Wrong Mobile NO... try again!");
        System.out.print("  Enter Mobile No.:" + " ");
        phone = input.next();
        if (phone.length() > 10 || phone.startsWith("0") == true)
            break;
    }
}

System.out.print("  Enter Blood Group Type (A, B or O):" + " ");
char blood =  input.next().charAt(0);

    while (blood != 'a' || blood != 'b' || blood != 'c'){
        System.out.println("Wrong Blood Group Type... try again!");
        System.out.println("    Enter Blood Group Type (A, B or O):" + " ");
        blood =  input.next().charAt(0);
        if (blood == 'A' || blood == 'B' || blood == 'O')
            break;    
    }

    a1[index] = name;
    a2[index] = phone;
    a3[index] = blood;
    a4[index] = 1;
    a5[index] = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! it works now! 
what a stupid mistake!
after posting the question i remembered that the call stack (the stack ) deletes the values after the method is finished

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes here.

First of you should really gather all the information you need in a class. That way you could easily store it all in one array.

```
public class donor{
String name;
String mobile
...
}
```

Secondly since you don't know how many inputs you are getting and array is really a stupid way of storing it. If you use a list you can simply do:

```
List<Donor> donors = new ArrayList<>();
donors.add(donor);
```

If you need to use an array you could try to use a counter. I would probably do it something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] name = new String[20];
    String[] mobile = new String[20];
    char[] bloodGroup = new char[20];
    int[] countODonation = new int[20];
    int[] bloodStock = new int[20];
    int counter = 0;
    boolean continue = true;
    while (continue){
        displayMainMenu();

    String choice = readAndVerify();
        switch (choice){
            case "1":
                name[counter] = readName();
                ...
                counter++;            
                break;
        }
       if (choice.equals("e"))
          continue = false; 
      }
}
```

But once again you should really use a class for the donor stuff. And a list.

Comment: i do realize that, but as i said  i am a novice and the course that i am attending only covers the very basics 
primitive data types - scanner - if statement - switch - loops - methods - arrays

and for this homework we are not allowed to use anything outside the course syllabus

but  thank you very much for taking a minute from your time and writing this reply, i will save this solution for next level

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a java question as much as it is a debug question. Your counter is local to the method it is in, so every time the method gets called the counter gets reset.

A variable has a scope. The scope of a variable depends on where you define it. Inside a method block (or inside the parameter section) a variable will live as long as the method block. If defined inside a class as non-static it will live as long as the instance. If defined as static inside a class it will live as long as the class (most of the time this means forever)

In your case you have 2 options: Either you make the variable static, define it outside of your addDonor method and pass it down into the addDonor method by value (so you cannot increment it inside addDonor, do this whereever you call addDonor).

If you go with the static variable then your code remains unchanged. Static variables generally are defined at the top of the class.

If you go with the passing variable down into addDonor then the main method becomes responsible for keeping and incrementing the counter variable. Make sure it only gets incremented on a succesful iteration.

There are other things you can do but they need you to know about Objects.